# Android: Standard icons android.R.drawable with other color

Tags: android, user-interface, icons, ui-design

Most of the standard icons of Android in `android.R.drawable` are gray in color.

I want to use them in other color, that match to my app colors. And I don't want to create copy of these icons and paint them in Photoshop or any painting application.

Is there any way to change their color in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with [Drawable.setColorFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter%28int,%20android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode%29), [here's](http://www.syedgakbar.com/blog/?p=442) a related tutorial.